# function call in background worker thread get executed only after main thread execution complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am calling a function on background worker thread which requires `ListBox` to be passed as parameter which intialize on main thread. I am using following code to do

```
   private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();           
        GetData()         

    }
void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {           
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            ShowLoadingPanel(listBox);
        }));            
    }

private void GetData()
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "raj", "raj", "raj", i });
        }
    }

  void ShowLoadingPanel(Control control)
   {
      //Doing some work here
   }
```

Problem is that `ShowLoadingPanel` function called only after `GetData` function completes its execution. I want this two function run parallel in different threads.

How can i do this ??

Comment: Why using a `BackgroundWorker` if you make all the job in the UI thread?

Comment: Both GetData and ShowLoadingPanel run on the UI thread.  It can do only one thing at a time.  The classic mistake here is that you are doing it backwards.  It should be GetData() that you run in the worker.  Leaving the UI thread to display the "loading panel".

Comment: @HansPassant I know it that making reverse of it will do the trick. But i have no of grids in my application. Do i need to all the data retrival for those in background to show loading panel. That's why i am looking for something different

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ShowLoadingPanel(listBox);    
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();       
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{           
    GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "raj", "raj", "raj", i });
    }
}

void ShowLoadingPanel(Control control)
{
   //Doing some work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eli, I know this will do it correctly.. But i need to run `ShowLoadingPanel` function in background !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make much sense: you want to offload `ShowLoadingPanel` to another (non-GUI) thread, but you execute it with [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) which is documented as *Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.*, i.e. executes on the GUI thread.

`Control.Invoke` posts a message to the message queue of the thread owning the form window and you do it from button `Click` handler which is already handled as a message. Thus, the message posted to the queue by `Control.Invoke` can only be processed after your `Click` handler exits, which is exactly what you observe.

Comment: so what can i do for two function to run simultenously.. as i am passing listbox into function as parameter, it cause exception other wise for cross thread exception

Comment: well, you should only modify controls on GUI thread anyway, so you should not do it in parallel. What exactly is the slow part?

Comment: I need to show control like loading panel while data is being populated in winform..

Comment: what is a loading panel, something like spinner image?

Comment: Yes something like gif animated image which makes users realize that data is being populated like wait form ..

Comment: well, your `GetData` doesn't touch GUI controls so put that in another thread?